# How to off android default keyboard when i pressed on editText

Tags: android

I would like to off android default keyboard when i pressed at editText. Such that the default keyboard will not popup.
I have tried folloing code but didn't worked:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lltest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText0"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </EditText>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And code is:

```
    edtEdit1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

InputMethodManager imm =                          (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtEdit1.getWindowToken(), 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: try using return true; in place of return false;

Comment: Refer following links http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/737442 http://stackoverflow.com/a/5484683/737442 http://stackoverflow.com/a/2429753/737442

Comment: did our answers help you or what ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
 android:editable="false"
```

in you xml declaration of edit text??

Answer (score 1):

for hidden

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

for show

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You put 1 instead of 0

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

To prevent the Android keyboard from appearing when an `EditText` is touched, just return **true** in the `onTouch()` method.

```
edtEdit1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```